# Sum of parsed javascript numbers isn't equal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the sum of 4 values using Javascript and the Angular framework. Everything is working fine for the most part except that in some very specific cases, the result is off.

This is what i'm doing

```
var grandTotal = Number($scope.Quote.BundlePrice) + Number($scope.Quote.InstallationFees) + Number($scope.Quote.ShippingFees) + Number($scope.Quote.Taxes);
$scope.Quote.GrandTotal = grandTotal
```

If I use these values

```
BundlePrice = "50.01"
InstallationFees = "20"
ShippingFees = "10"
Taxes = "11.99"
```

The Grand Total value I get on my webpage is **91.99999999999999** when it should be **92**

I did a console log of the strings i'm trying to parse and everything seems to be fine there as well, this is what i'm getting. Values are in order.

```
50.01 and 20 and 10 and 11.99
```

Any hints on what could possible be causing this problem?
I've tried using **parseFloat**, still didn't work. I tried to add **toFixed(2)** at the end as well but the same problem is happening and I can't seem to find anyone having the same problem as me.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: Oh wow, I never saw this page even after my search. Thanks alot!

Comment: Javascript is known to have a rounding problem. So it is easiest to just round the number to the nearest hundredths place:

    `$scope.Quote.GrandTotal = grandTotal.toFixed(2);`

Comment: This seems to always work since whenever it's off it's always .999999. Your fix worked, I thought this was going to strip the number to only have 2 digits, but I guess I was wrong.